# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: 4

Tags: php, mysql

I've been working on a school project which I didn't have a problem to, suddenly this error appears. I didn't edit something on the code. When I run it again this error appears.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7' 
>   And here is the other error I've been getting.
>
> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7

This is the query that I made. I really could not find what the problem is.

```
    class Subject {        

    function getSubjectList($id) {
        global $db;            

        $sql = "SELECT class_id, c.subject_id, subject_desc, units, day, time
                FROM class c 
                JOIN subject s 
                ON  c.subject_id = s.subject_id
                JOIN lecturer l 
                ON c.lec_id = l.lec_id 
                WHERE l.lec_id = $id";

        $stmt = $db->query($sql);

        while($r = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $result[] = $r['class_id'];
            $result[] = $r['subject_id'];
            $result[] = $r['subject_desc'];
            $result[] = $r['units']; 
            $result[] = $r['day'];
            $result[] = $r["time"];
            $result[] = $r['class_id'];
        }

        return $result;            
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend you parametrise your query.  Have you tried echoing the query to see what it looks like? `echo $sql; die();`

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new to this, but how do I do that?

Comment: Most likely cause `$id` is an empty string? (And yes, use prepared statements)

Comment: Have a browse through this page: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers#Running_Statements_With_Parameters It explains how to add parameters to a query.  For more details, refer to the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php

Comment: I've already resolve it. The problem was the data that is being passed through function was the problem. The $id is indeed empty. Thanks @Wrikken

Answer (score -1):

On this query, you have to specify the join type: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Look the example below:

```
SELECT class_id, c.subject_id, subject_desc, units, day, time
                FROM class c 
                INNER JOIN subject s 
                ON  c.subject_id = s.subject_id
                INNER JOIN lecturer l 
                ON c.lec_id = l.lec_id 
                WHERE l.lec_id = $id;
```